# Proof Writing: Regarding an equivalent statement of the Axiom of Choice. (Tao, Analysis I: Exercise 8.4.2.)

Tags: proof-writing, axiom-of-choice

I am trying to prove the converse (underlined in red) by defining a choice function $f:\Bbb{F}\rightarrow \cup_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$ to be $f(X_\alpha)=x_\alpha$ such that $Y\cap X_\alpha=x_\alpha$ where $x_\alpha$ is a unique intersection between $Y$ and $X_\alpha$. Also, $\Bbb{F}=\{X_\alpha: \alpha\in I\}$. I do not understand the problem where the Axiom of Choice does not assume the sets $X_\alpha$ being disjoint. In a same post here [Exercise on the Axiom of Choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947956/exercise-on-the-axiom-of-choice), Prof. Brian Scott said that if the family of $X_\alpha$ is not pairwaise disjoint then there's no way we can get the $Y$ we want to use to define $f$. Why?

[image]

Comment: Let me point out that you're confusing $x_\alpha$ with $\{x_\alpha\}$. The unique element in an intersection is *not* the intersection itself.

Comment: The hint shown is actually the ordered pair form of the power set form of AoC?

Comment: I don't know what is the "ordered pair form of the power set form of AoC". The hint is just to get a choice function, as directly as possible.